# State Updates are Merged

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I read the react document: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Code here:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      comments: []
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetchPosts().then(response => {
      this.setState({
        posts: response.posts
      });
    });

    fetchComments().then(response => {
      this.setState({
        comments: response.comments
      });
    });
  }
```

Why this.setState({comments}) leaves this.state.posts intact, but completely replaces this.state.comments? Why this.state.posts is not changed?

Comment: Your question is answered directly by the doc: "When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the current state."

Comment: I misunderstood. "When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the current state." is the direct answer.